# Webmatrix if statement issues. any ideas?

Tags: razor, if-statement, webmatrix

I have written a SQL query, which extracts the lowest weekly price for a property stored in my database:

```
var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];
var cheapestrate = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM RateInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0 ORDER BY RateWeekly ASC";
var qcheapestrate = db.QuerySingle (cheapestrate, rPropertyId);
```

I'm pretty confident that this statement is correct. The problem i have, is that not ALL propertys have pricing, so i only want to show this price if they do. I have created the below if statement, but it's telling me i'm missing an ; somewhere?

```
@if(qcheapestrate=!null){
Rates From qcheapestrate.rateweekly per week
}
```

So i'm trying to check if the query returns an entry. if it does, i want to show the lowest "rateweekly" value. Hopefully this all makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
@if(qcheapestrate!=null){
<text>Rates From</text>
@qcheapestrate.rateweekly
<text>per week</text>
}
```

Comment: also, your comparison operator is backwards - =! needs to be !=

Comment: You should explain why this fixes the problem.

Comment: My guess is that razor has trouble transitioning from code to raw text in certain cases. Here, it isn't recognizing that "Rates from" is not code. The text markup tells the view engine explicitly that it is raw text, not code. The @ delimiter then tells the view engine explicitly that "qcheapestrate.rateweekly" is code...

As I understand it, razor markup is supposed to allow you to move from raw text to code and back without telling it explicitly, but it doesn't always work in practice.

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. You have to tell Razor if you are going from code to output - especially if that output is raw text.

Comment: Ah. Its the markup that signifies the change to the view engine. Is that correct? So if Gavin5511's text is wrapped in any markup, it will work?

Comment: works perfectly, thank you! FYI, i did need to change around the =! to != but i couldn't edit your post, so you may want to do it, just in case someone else needs to use the example :) many thanks dude